# Как выводить изображение по GET запросу?

Tags: php

С GET я знаком, а вот как выводить jpg, txt, js и так далее, не умею.

Comment: @entithat а что уточнять если точно задал вопрос?

Comment: примерно так: site.com?getfile=txt  - получаю содержимое файла

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$filename = $_GET('filename');

if(file_exists($filename)){
    // Получаем MimeType
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    // Передаем его клиенту
    header('Content-Type: ' . finfo_file($finfo, $filename));
    finfo_close($finfo);

    // Говорим клиенту под каким именем сохранить файл.
    // Если эту строку закомментировать, то браузер, вместо выдачи окна Save As отобразит содержимое в браузере
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($filename));

    // Не нужно кешировать. Если файл по одному адресу всегда выдается один и тот же, то этот блок не нужен
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');

    // Говорим какой размер передаваемого файла
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));

    // Собственно, передаем сам файл
    readfile($filename);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

отправляете заголовок типа контента, выводите файл

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
readfile("/path/to/file.jpg");
```